# Python: process list of large data-structure Objects efficiently

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to READ and MODIFY elements in the list of same large user-defined data structure (including numpy.array, list, dict, ...).

```
class DataStruct:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, others) -> None:
        self.a = a # numpy.array
        self.b = b # numpy array
        self.c = c # numpy array
        self.others = others

    def update_a(self, value):
        pass

    def update_b(self, value):
        pass

    def update_c(self, value):
        pass

    def update_others(self, values):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # run algorithm by processing (a, b, c, others)
        pass
```

I tried to use multiprocessing package, one process will serve for an object but the performance is even much slower then process the list in serial. The reason is that the multiprocessing needs to copy the data I parse to a process and the interval to launch processes. Is there any way to share memory among processes for data-structure objects or to avoid copying data?

I already tried to use multiprocessing.Queue or Manager but it does not help. I also tried Ray package but it does not allow modify the object except for copying it locally

Comment: Have you tried `mmap`?

Comment: I could not find the example to apply mmap for user-defined data structure. Could you provide the link or example?

Comment: Check [here](https://realpython.com/python-mmap/#:~:text=Python's%20mmap%20provides%20memory-mapped,lot%20of%20file%20I%2FO.)

Comment: Your question is a bit broad as it is. What _actual_ operations do you need to do? Would the "large structure" be flattenable to e.g. a key-value list, etc.?

Comment: I have updated the question. For using mmap, it is hard to make shared memory for fields in the class because they have different type (array, list, dictionary, ...)

Comment: I will suggest you to use Numba instead of Numpy. It will definitely improve the speed.https://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: You need to divide the data such that each process gets a subset of it and performs work on that. Using instance methods passes the entire data stored in the instance to each process, even if they never work on it. So, make the target functions staticmethods which process a  subset of a,b and c and return the processed chunk. Then in the main process you concatenate the processes chunk. This way, you limit the data that needs to be sent to each worker

Comment: However, if the workers actually need the entire data in the instance to start their work, then it might not be worth it use multiprocessing